# Kendo TreeList Datasource From Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-treelist

I create a kendo TreeList like this

```
@(Html.Kendo().TreeList<BEL.EmpTreeBEL>()
    .Name("treelist")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Add().Field(e => e.EmpName).Width(250).Title("First Name");
        columns.Add().Field(e => e.EmpDept).Title("Departemen Name");
    })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .ServerOperation(false)
        .Read(read => read.Action("All", "Home"))
        .Model(m => {
            m.Id(f => f.EmpId);
            m.ParentId(f => f.ReportTo);
            m.Field(f => f.EmpName);
            m.Field(f => f.EmpDept);
            m.Field(f => f.ReportTo);
            m.Expanded(true);
        })
    )    
)
```

and the data populate from this

```
public JsonResult All([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            var result = new EmployeeBLL().EmpListTree.ToTreeDataSourceResult(request,
                e => e.EmpId,
                e => e.ReportTo
            );

            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

The problem is, my kendo TreeList only show the parent, and not the child

I get that code from the telerik documentations, there is some code that i don't understand

```
var result = GetDirectory().ToTreeDataSourceResult(request,
                e => e.EmployeeID,
                e => e.ReportsTo,
                e => id.HasValue ? e.ReportsTo == id : e.ReportsTo == null,
                e => e.ToEmployeeDirectoryModel() //i don't understand this part
            );
```

What i'm doing wrong?
Should i create kendo TreeList from javascript? Instead of using Html.Kendo().TreeList?

Thank You
Sorry for My bad english

Comment: check this link code seems different
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/treeview/index

Comment: @REDEVI_ that is treeview, im using treelist